# Symfony2: $form->isValid() always returns true

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I create a form type *UserBundle/form/UserType.php*.

`$form->isValid()` returns true if the username or the email exist even if other fields are empty.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    private $type;
    const TYPE_CREATE = 1;

    public function __construct($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        switch ($this->type){
            case self::TYPE_CREATE :
                $builder
                    ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'user.email'))
                    ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'user.name'))
                    ;
                break;
            default :
                $builder
                    ->add('username')
                    ->add('usernameCanonical')
                    ->add('email')
                    ->add('emailCanonical')
                    ->add('enabled')
                    ->add('salt')
                    ->add('password')
                    ->add('lastLogin')
                    ->add('locked')
                    ->add('expired')
                    ->add('expiresAt')
                    ->add('confirmationToken')
                    ->add('passwordRequestedAt')
                    ->add('roles')
                    ->add('credentialsExpired')
                    ->add('credentialsExpireAt')
                ;
                break;
        }

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'project_userbundle_user';
    }
}
```

And my controller

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function CreateAction()
    {
        //create user
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();

        //create form
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(UserType::TYPE_CREATE),$user);

        //form submit
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        if($request->getMethod() === "POST"){
            $form->submit($request);
            //test if form is valid
            if($form->isValid()){
                //generate random password
                $password = User::randomPassword();
                $user->setPassword($password);

                //save user
                $userManager->updateUser($user);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('Project:User:create.html.twig',array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you re-creating the request object ??? What's wrong with asking it in your method parameter? Or getting it from `$this->getRequest()`? Or getting it from `$this->get('request')`?

Comment: Where is $form->handleRequest($request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Validation Constraints NotNull or NotBlank ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html ).

My guess is that, default "required=true" on fields isn't working because You are recreating request.

Answer (score 2):

**tip:**

You shouldn't try to re-create the `Request` inside a controller. It is definitely a bad practice and can lead to undesired behavior of your application - as you're currently experiencing.

symfony will pass the request automatically to your controller actions if you add it as a method parameter:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
   // $request is holding the current request
}
```

Further you can get the current request from the container inside a `ContainerAware` class like a controller.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request = $this->get('request');
$request = $this->container->get('request');
```

---

Further please stick with the [symfony coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html). There are multiple violations in your code.

Method names should be  *lower camelCased* not *CamelCased*.

`UserBundle/form` should be `UserBundle/Form`.

A method's opening curly brackets/braces belong to the next line.

```
public function __construct($type) // {
{
    $this->type = $type;
}
```